# Deriving variances of simple linear regression coefficients

Tags: variance, regression-coefficients

I am having a difficult time understanding how to prove the formulas for the variance of the parameters (beta0 and beta1) in SLR form. I have no idea how to start this problem...any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

where T is the time, and is ranges from t = 1, 2, ..., T

Edit: I have tried to leverage the matrix form of the variance of the estimators using Var(B) = (sigma^2) * (X'X)^-1, but I am unable to manipulate my resulting 2 by 2 matrix (along the diagonal) to determine the variances of each estimator.

Comment: Please tell us what "$T$" means.  I would surmise that time has been recorded as a sequence of $T$ consecutive integers, but that assumption is nowhere in evidence in your post. Furthermore, even when this is the case the variance of $\hat\beta_0$ depends crucially on what the first time value is.

Comment: T is indeed the the and sequence of T consecutive integers.

Comment: t begins at 1 and continues to T (t=1,2,3,...,T)

Comment: Good: you now have enough information to apply the formulas for the variances.

Comment: I tried to leverage the matrix form of the variance of the estimators using Var(B) = (sigma^2) * (X'X)^-1, but I am unable to manipulate my resulting 2 by 2 matrix (along the diagonal) to determine the variances for each estimator.

Comment: That's good: it establishes a context for people to help you further.  I recommend editing your post to include this information.  Consider also displaying the expressions you have obtained for the components of $X^\prime X$ or its inverse.